# C++ "Error expected a ')'"

Tags: c++, sfml

Visual Studio is giving me an odd error when running my C++ program.  I even copied and pasted the code from SFML's website, but for some reason after window (sf::VideoMode Visual Studio says "Eror, expected a ')'".  When I run the program, it gives error C2226 on line 8 (the render window one).  What am I missing?

```
#pragma once

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/Window.hpp"

class AirportGame {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window"); // This line
public:
    void init();

    void tick();

    void render();

    int main();
};
```

Comment: @Ranveer that's not correct, you can include local files with "path.extension"

Comment: int main() is unrelated to the entrance method.

Comment: Nope, its in SFML/Graphics.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window"); // This line`

Is this the same as TYPE function(function(arg, arg), arg); ?

Can you have functions sitting there in class definitions like that? I think it expects a ) after window(

I think it needs to go in the functionality section of your code

Comment: Whoops. Duh.  I fixed that, but now I get an unable to read memory at 0xCCCCCCC0 every time the window loads.  The window definitely gets created, and when I went through the debugger to look for 0xCCCCCCC0 I couldn't find anything.  Let me know if I should post more code

Comment: Should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes I think so, that or go to sleep :P

Comment: Going to sleep would make more sense, but I'll post the question first :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966064/opening-sfml-window-gives-memory-read-error tada

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a constructor call in your variable declaration. You will need to use an initializer list or make your RenderWindow variable a pointer and create the instance in your constructor with `new`. Don't forget to `delete` it in the destructor or use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` from the start.

While we are at at, your `main` method won't work this way. It needs to be a free function, not a class method.

Comment: The 'main' method is unrelated to the entrance point.  Check my comment on FaddishWorm's answer please

Comment: Update your code please, or ask a new question if this syntax problem is resolved. We don't know what your code looks like now.