# Opening SFML window gives memory read error

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to open a SFML window, but every time it is launched it says "Access violation reading location: 0xCCCCCCC0." The error is occuring in the init() method. Relevant code:

```
class AirportGame {
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
public:
    void init();
    int run();
```

/

```
void AirportGame::init() {
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
}

int AirportGame::run() {
    init();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    AirportGame* app = new AirportGame();
    return app->run();
}
```

It happens sometime after init, because the actual window is open.  There is no mention in the debugger of 0xCCCCCC0.

Comment: do you not have debugging symbols turned on? why are you going on mem address?

Comment: their turned on, but I'm saying every object appears to be properly defined, including window.

Comment: yar, its a runtime error though :P - Should window be a pointer?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean haha

Comment: put a print message in at every line so you can see where it is failing. I am guessing when you call window.isOpen() it is failing, but its too vague to tell from a memory address.

Comment: The error occurs on this line: window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

Comment: Don't you need to do something like window = new window(); or is SFML magical?

Comment: I changed window to a pointer and replaced the code in init with `window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");` and still same problem

Comment: @FaddishWorm: SFML isn't magical; C++ is.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: And now you've just *ruined* one fresh young mind who was about to have a promising C++ career... :-(

Comment: @Tips48: You shouldn't use `new` in C++ unless you absolutely know expertly that there's a pressing reason to do so.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's what I thought, hence why I wasn't using it.  That doesn't explain the error though

Comment: @Tips48: No, it doesn't. Using a debugger will help you with that.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's wrong with using 'new'?

Comment: Show us where you create the instance of `AirportGame` you're calling the `run` function on.

Comment: I'll update the op with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!

Turns out under the C++ pre-processor I set the definition to SFML_STATIC instead of SFML_DYNAMIC

Answer (score -1):

Set window to a
RenderWindow *window;

and create it with

```
window = new sf::RenderWindow( /*your stuff or default initialize*/ );
```

and then call

```
window->create( /*your settings*/ );
```

if you didn't already initialize it.

From then on just access window using '->' instead of '.'

Comment: yea thats what I was getting at.

Comment: You should never use `new` unless there's a good reason to. Why do you think heap allocation would make any difference to this problem?

Comment: Well it's what I have always used and it works well.
Using new isn't that much of a problem, as long as you use delete when you're finished.