# What is wrong with using the new operator?

Tags: c++, standards, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I was recently told off on this site for using the `new` operator but I didn't get a response when I asked why.
So my question is: is there actually something bad about using `new`?

The only reason I can think of is a memory leak when a `new` call isn't paired with a `delete` call.

Comment: Where is the hyperlink ?

Comment: How are we supposed to know why you were told off when you don't share the context?

Comment: Oh this was just a question about good form, but it was as an answer to and posted in the comments of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966064/opening-sfml-window-gives-memory-read-error/20966403#20966403

Comment: Ok - so there an object was created in `main` using `new`, when it could have more easily, efficiently, concisely and reliably been put on the stack - notice that the programmer forgot to `delete` it before returning from `main()`, which is indicative of the kinds of errors.  Most of the time for application level programming you'll have some containers like `vector` or `map` that can store values without you explicitly using `new`.  You may need to use `new` in a factory method, for `pImpl` and polymorphic state "machines", but they probably qualifiy as "expertly" in Kerrek's comment.

Comment: Oh that makes sense thanks. And by "put on the stack" you do just mean a variable in the class as opposed to a pointer to the object right?

Comment: Yes - `AirportGame app; app.run();`.  Dynamic allocation requires compile time tracking of which memory's in use - it's relatively expensive (= CPU eating = slow) (not just in C++ but inherently in any language, and more so with garbage collection).  Memory for the stack is calculated at compile time and the stack pointer's typically just adjusted and restored on function entry and exit - *very* fast.

Comment: If you wanted a response to your question about that comment, you should have used @username before your comment, so the user that made that comment about new would get a notification that you replied to him.

Comment: @rozina I did, in the main comment section where another user said the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't told off.  A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966403/198536) said:

> You should never use `new` unless there's a good reason to.

This is currently +2 (two upvotes agreeing with the comment).

In the case of your example, using `new` is optional.  You could have just as easily instantiated the object on the stack with:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(...);
```

This has the advantage of not needing an explicit `delete` and no way for the object to escape destruction when it is no longer needed.

On a scale of zero (completely harmless) to ten (destroys lives and property), using `new` instead is maybe a 1.  Still, it can drive some programmers crazy when they see it because of severe <s>childhood</s> early trauma being bitten by this kind of malfeasance.